# Can't login to gmail using selenium module in python

Tags: python

Hello this is my first question here on stackoverflow. My code looks like:

```py
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window() #For maximizing window
browser.implicitly_wait(20) #gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
browser.get('http://google.com/gmail/about/')
sign_in = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in')
sign_in.click()
Email=browser.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
Email.send_keys('abc')
eNext = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
eNext.click()
Password=browser.find_element_by_name('password')
Password.clear()
Password.send_keys('xyz')
pNext = browser.find_element_by_id('passwordNext')
pNext.click()
```

I am getting the error stated below please help. 
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="identifierId"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.122)`

Comment: Seems that this identifier not exists

Comment: Check for the element id of `identifierId` if it is spelled right and if you have it on webpage

Comment: <input type="email" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Email or phone" name="identifier" value="" autocapitalize="none" id="identifierId" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">

Comment: This is the html for the email object

Comment: Can you try: `WebElement elementName = driver.findElement(By.ID("identifierId"));` more details: [https://www.guru99.com/find-element-selenium.html](https://www.guru99.com/find-element-selenium.html)

Comment: so i figured out that the problem was that i wasn't taking into account the switching of the tabs therefore i added the line: __browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])__
before the sign-in page opens